# SQLite query get's me a result 1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

Hello everyone I keep getting a result 1 one my query, even though the same exact syntax works on SQLite query browser

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"amstations" ofType:@"db"];
sqlite3 *database;
if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String],&database) == !SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"DB Did not open");
}
else {
    NSString *theState = [states objectAtIndex:[thePickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]];

    NSString *sqlStatement;
    if ([pickView selectedRowInComponent:0] == 0)
    {
        sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM stations WHERE state like '%@ %'",theState];
    }
    else if ([pickView selectedRowInComponent:0] == 1)
    {
        sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM stations WHERE state like '%@ %' ORDER BY format",theState];
    }
    else if ([pickView selectedRowInComponent:0] == 2)
    {
        sqlStatement = (@"SELECT state, power || ' kW' power FROM ( SELECT state, Cast(Rtrim(power, 'kW') AS 'numeric') power FROM stations WHERE state LIKE '%CA%' ORDER BY power)");
    }
    else
    {
        sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM stations WHERE state like '%@ %' ORDER BY city",theState];
    }

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil);
    NSLog(@"result: %i", result);

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"prepare succeeded");
        NSLog(@"%@",sqlStatement);
        city = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

If I put a simple query like "SELECT * FROM stations WHERE state LIKE 'CA'" it works.

Comment: Can you add some code relating to how you are using/executing this query string?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'result 1 one' -- can you elaborate please?  What exactly is giving you what result?  Are you getting one record?

Comment: a succesful SQLite query get's a result = 0 (SQLITE_OK) but a 1 result is an error in the query (SQLITE_ERROR)

Comment: your code and query string branches by `[pickView selectedRowInComponent:0]`. In which case do you see the error?

Comment: I get the error from this statement: sqlStatement = (@"SELECT state, power || ' kW' power FROM ( SELECT state, Cast(Rtrim(power, 'kW') AS 'numeric') power FROM stations WHERE state LIKE '%CA%' ORDER BY power)");